# Convert an Applescript works fine on Lion but not in Maverick

Tags: applescript

```
tell application "System Preferences" to activate
delay 0

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click the menu item "Universal Access" of the menu "View" of menu bar 1
        click the radio button "Seeing" of the first tab group of window "Universal Access"
        click the checkbox "Use grayscale" of tab group 1 of window "Universal Access"
    end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

I used to able to use above Applescript which cause screen to be gray scale until update to Maverick.  But it does not work with Maverick occurring an `error "System Events got an error: Can’t get menu item \"Universal Access\" of menu \"View\" of menu bar 1 of process \"System Preferences\"." number -1728 from menu item "Universal Access" of menu "View" of menu bar 1 of process "System Preferences"`.  Does anybody know which parts need to be changed to work with Maverick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes are the name of the pane, the name of the window, there is no radio button and tab group 1.

Try this script:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    launch
    reveal anchor "Seeing_Display" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    click checkbox "Use grayscale" of window "Accessibility" of process "System Preferences"
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```